# Javascript newDate() and Date.now() are showing the same time for things uploaded at different time

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I am uploading two pictures at different times (about 10 minutes apart) but both new Date() and Date.now() are showing the same time in the database. I have checked it a few times and uploaded them about 10-15 minutes apart but still they are showing the same time.

In my schema, I have used new Date() and Date.now() for the created time of the posts.

here, 'created' is used for the posts and used in the post model and 'createdAt' is used for retrieving the posts from the posts array in the user model.

[image: this is the schema for the post model]

[image: this is the schema for the user model]

[image: this is the database of the user model]

[image: this is the database of the post model]

Comment: You are passing the time at which the server was started, because you call `Date.now()` yourself. Instead, let it call it whenever an element is created by simply passing the function: `default: Date.now`